How does one get new URL() (for a web worker) that Vitest can recognise in a React integration test?
I instantiate a new web worker within one of my React components
const MyComponent = () => {
    ...
    const worker = new Worker(
        new URL('../../../path/to/my-worker.ts', import.meta.url)
    );
    ...
}

and it runs fine in the browser. However when I run a Vitest integration test on MyComponent, I get the following message
Error: Failed to load url C:/src/path/to/my-worker.ts?worker_file&type=classic

I have @vitest/web-worker installed as a dev dependency
"@vitest/web-worker": "^2.0.5"

vite.config.ts fyi:
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import VitePluginLinaria from 'vite-plugin-linaria';

import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import wyw from '@wyw-in-js/vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    VitePluginLinaria(),
    wyw({
      include: ['**/*.{ts,tsx}'],
      babelOptions: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-typescript', '@babel/preset-react'],
      },
    }),
  ],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    css: true,
    setupFiles: ['./__tests__/setup.ts', '@vitest/web-worker'],
  },
});


Did you follow the other recommendations? For example, that you must use self.onmessage or Vitest won't work.

yes but thx jose

I tried to follow your code snippets, and it worked for me. See the example in my repo: https://github.com/githubjakob/vitest-webworker-test/ Is this what you are trying to achieve or did I miss anything?

Try this:
replace from
const MyComponent = () => {
    ...
    const worker = new Worker(
        new URL('../../../path/to/my-worker.ts', import.meta.url)
    );
    ...
}

to
const MyComponent = () => {
    ...
    const worker = new Worker(
        new URL('../../../path/to/my-worker.ts', import.meta.url),
        { type: 'module' }
    );
    ...
}

